# Spring Custom Method During Bean Life Cycle(Init and Destroy)

Tags: java, spring

Though I have worked on spring but I just wanted to see the life Cycle of Bean.

Therefore I made a simple project and stumble upon something weird where the result of bean life cycle I observed in a tutorial and in my eclipse project Please look at the attachment given below:

My eclipse Project:

[image: in Info log I am getting first Closing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext then init is onvoked]

Observation of a bean life cycle in a tutorial:

[image: Here life cycle is working fine]

Can anyone shed some light why this behaviour? In my project its closing bean before init method is invoked

```
public class CurrentAccount implements Account {

    @Autowired
    private Card creditCard;


    public void setCreditCard(Card creditCard) {
        this.creditCard = creditCard;
    }

    @Override
    public String createAccount() {
        return "Current Account Created Successfully";
    }

    @Override
    public String cardDetails() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this.creditCard.cardDetails();
    }

    public void onInit() {
        System.out.println("Init method has been invoked");
    }
    public void onDestroy() {
        System.out.println("Destroy method has been invoked");
    }
}
```

Okay I figured out that it has some random order behaviour still I am posting this implemented method where init and destro method is written

Comment: Can you share the implementations?

Comment: @uli shared but please look at comment below the implementation class(edited version) and consider it then answer please.

Comment: Congratulations! You found the solution. It is awesome.